# Django admin field display

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

## This is my Device that I registered in admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Device)
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  search_fields = ["device_type","serial_number","in_use_by","brand","model","type_number","mac_address"]
  list_display = ("device_type","serial_number","in_use_by","brand","model","type_number","mac_address","invoice",)
  list_filter = ("device_type","in_use_by","brand",)
```

## This is my Device model in models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_type         = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    serial_number       = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    in_use_by           = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    brand               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    model               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    type_number         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True, default = None)
    mac_address         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True, default = None)
    invoice             = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
```

## This is my form class from forms.py

```
class ReturnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {"device_type": forms.Select(attrs={"class":"custom-select col-sm-4"})}
        exclude = ("serial_number","in_use_by","brand","mac_address","type_number","model","invoice",)
```

Now, when I view my admin panel, the invoice gets displayed as a column name in the panel. But, when I view an object in more detail by clicking it, the invoice field is not displayed.

[image: outer view]

[image: inner detailed view]

What is the problem that has occured?
How can I resolve this issue?
Requesting immediate help.

Comment: Why do you using `exclude` in forms if you are using `__all__` fields in the model form?

Comment: I will change it later

Answer (score 0):

`BinaryField` can not be used in a ModelForm, and thus I suspect it also can't be displayed in the admin's change form. You can consult the documentation on BinaryField here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield .

Also note the warning about abusing BinaryField to store files in the database.

Comment: I basically want to store file in a database through admin panel. If the above case dosen't work then, how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: @AishwaryShukla storing files in the database is a bad idea 99% of the time, as the documentation says. Better would be to use a `FileField` to store the files on disk. But that is outside the scope of your current question.

Comment: But, the condition in front of me asks me to store it in the database irrespective of the performance. Can you suggest how should I store it in the Database?

Comment: @AishwaryShukla sorry but I'm not sure how you would do that in this case.

Comment: What else should one use to get a checkbox?